# Cannot open shared library (so) on Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, linux, arm, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am trying to run a ARM shared object binary compiled for Android (found within an .apk) on Raspberry PI ARM machine.

Unfortunately the binary is closed source and I cannot recompile it for the os which runs on  raspberry pi (raspian, debian derivation)

Quick question: Is it possible to run such a .so compiled for android on raspberry pi? I uploaded the binary here: http://www.speedyshare.com/MSXq9/libfoo.so (Sorry for inconvenient download).

I found this similar question here [Running ARM binaries for Android on Linux ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383813/running-arm-binaries-for-android-on-linux-arm) and it suggests that binaries won't run on other unix distros (I use a derivation of debian, raspian on my raspberry) since android's c library is Bionic.

Can one install bionic on debian? How could I manage to run this library?

**All the following output was generated on the rasbperry machine were I want to run/load libfoo.so.**

When I try to load the .so file in python (before, I set LD_PRELOAD accordingly)

```
import ctypes 
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libfoo.so')
```

I get an OSError: *libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*.

But after looking on the strace output, it seems like the loader cannot load libfoo.so and thus fails with the slightly misleading error message *No such file or directory* (After all the .so is found and the loader tries to load it, but fails while doing so).

When issuing **readelf -h libfoo.so** I get

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# readelf -h libfoo.so 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x10b60
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          341440 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000002, has entry point, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         5
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         21
  Section header string table index: 20
```

Furthermore theh **attribute section aeabi** for libfoo.so (obtained with **readelf --all**)

```
No version information found in this file.
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "5TE"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v5TE
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
```

And in comparison the same output as above for a locally compiled .so on the raspberry platform where I am trying to run libfoo.so:

```
  Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "6"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v6
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

There are some differences in the CPU the shared libraries were compiled for, but I assume it sholdn't matter since ARM architectures are downwards compatible.

Here the strace output **for trying to load libfoo.so**:

```
  root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# strace ./test -s libfoo.so
execve("./test", ["./test", "-s", "libfoo.so"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x36f000
uname({sys="Linux", node="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f6a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 44, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f69000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\270\4\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 7276, SEEK_SET)                = 7276
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1080) = 1080
lseek(3, 7001, SEEK_SET)                = 7001
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10170, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 39740, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f3e000
mprotect(0xb6f40000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f47000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0xb6f47000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb6f69000, 44)                  = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/v6l/vfp/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/v6l/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/v6l", 0xbea66f20)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/vfp/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/vfp", 0xbea66f20)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls", 0xbea66f20)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v6l/vfp/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f20)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/v6l/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/v6l", 0xbea66f20)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/vfp/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/vfp", 0xbea66f20)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=43090, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 43090, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f33000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0(\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8652, SEEK_SET)                = 8652
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 8320, SEEK_SET)                = 8320
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9812, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 41136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f28000
mprotect(0xb6f2a000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f31000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0xb6f31000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\214y\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1198880, SEEK_SET)             = 1198880
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1360) = 1360
lseek(3, 1198444, SEEK_SET)             = 1198444
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1200240, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1242408, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6df8000
mprotect(0xb6f1b000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f22000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x122) = 0xb6f22000
mmap2(0xb6f25000, 9512, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f25000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f69000
set_tls(0xb6f694c0, 0xb6f69b98, 0xb6f6e048, 0xb6f694c0, 0xb6f6e048) = 0
mprotect(0xb6f22000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f31000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f6d000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6f33000, 43090)               = 0
open("/usr/lib/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0`\v\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 341440, SEEK_SET)              = 341440
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 840) = 840
lseek(3, 341224, SEEK_SET)              = 341224
read(3, "A(\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\36\0\0\0\0055TE\0\6\4\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25"..., 41) = 41
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=43090, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 43090, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f33000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/v6l", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tls", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/v6l", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vfp", 0xbea66f40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=28672, ...}) = 0
open("/lib/tls/v6l/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f40)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/v6l/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v6l", 0xbea66f40)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/vfp", 0xbea66f40)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0xbea66f40)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v6l/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v6l/vfp", 0xbea66f40)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/v6l/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v6l", 0xbea66f40)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/vfp/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/vfp", 0xbea66f40)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0`\v\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 341440, SEEK_SET)              = 341440
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 840) = 840
lseek(3, 341224, SEEK_SET)              = 341224
read(3, "A(\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\36\0\0\0\0055TE\0\6\4\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25"..., 41) = 41
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x36f000
brk(0x390000)                           = 0x390000
munmap(0xb6f33000, 43090)               = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f68000
write(1, "Service libfoo.so Not Fo"..., 115Service libfoo.so Not Found:  libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 115
write(1, "Problem calling generic_function"..., 91Problem calling generic_function_entry(): ./test: undefined symbol: generic_function_entry
) = 91
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You could probably make it work in a chroot, the trick would be if you should start with a "normal" android bionic libc and tools, or an android-on-pi one.  I suspect with enough work, you could create a custom build of bionic (including its dynamic linker) which could run alongside your normal debian pi setup (ie, without the chroot).  Make sure your ABIs are fully compatible though.  How come you don't have source?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @rakib: It seems like there is currently no Android that runs on the Raspberry Pi. If so, this would have been my favorite approach.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: I'll give it a try. Do you have by chance any tutorial that I can have a look on, which explains how to build a chroot with Bionic?

Comment: The download link gives 404, but I recognize this is quite an old question.

Comment: There are rumors of Google adding Raspberry Pi as officially supported Android target. For chroot running simplest of possible executables you should only need the essential libraries and dynamic linker like Chris Stratton comments above. Easiest is to use proper version of Android NDK installed on x86/amd64 machine to compile and link your executable. Seek NDK documentation for the differences of Android and plain Linux system - mainly Android kernel is missing some services but it also is adding some stuff, notably Binder IPC. I do not how much this affects Bionic libc, maybe not much.

Comment: While waiting for Raspberry Pi Android images (if there are none already in existence), you could find and build a compatible arm Android image for basic experimentation. It would be interesting to hear of any report how it works. :-)

Comment: have you found a way of doing it? is it loaded at the end?

Answer (score 0):

[libhybris](https://github.com/libhybris/libhybris) can use bionic-based HW adaptations in Glibc systems.
Conceptually libhybris is a custom version of the Bionic linker, with hooks replacing Bionic symbols with Glibc compatible ones.
It provides `android_dlopen`,`android_dlsym`  to use Android native libraries from glibc.

Comment: Linking to outside tutorials and resources is not recommended, especially when they're in a different language than English.